# JSP exception, "quote symbol expected"

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat, servlets

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<html>
<body>
<h1 align="center">blablalblalblab</h1>
<p>
<%
List styles = (List)request.getAttribute("styles");
Iterator it = styles.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    out.print("<br>try: " + it.next());
}
%>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

after executing my servlet request i'm getting error

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /result.jsp (line: 1, column: 18) quote symbol expected
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)

can't find any quotes that are not on right place.

Comment: I think you're not actually running the code which you've there in your question.

Comment: @axtavt had the right answer for me! use straight quotes not curvey ones.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use Java in JSPs, please. That's what the standard tag library is for.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
<body>
<h1 align="center">blablalblalblab</h1>
<p>
  <c:forEach items="${styles}" var="style">
    <br>try: ${style}
  </c:forEach>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In more detail:

1. Embedding Java code in a JSP makes the page difficult to read (JSP is a tag-oriented language), difficult to maintain, and difficult to debug.
2. The standard tag libraries are already debugged, have plentiful documentation and examples, and probably already Do What You Want To Do.
3. If you truly have some logic that needs to be performed in Java and no pre-existing tags exist, you can either a) put the logic in a bean and call it via JSTL or b) write your own tag using tagfiles.

Why is Java code better in a bean or tag library than in a JSP?

1. Testing is a big factor: beans and tag libraries can be tested
   outside of a running servlet environment with ease.
2. Tag libraries are reusable and significantly cleaner than JSP includes.

Comment: try answering the question instead of hectoring the OP.

Comment: Sometimes the answer to a question is not a direct response. He'll have considerably more success with a JSTL method of iterating a list in a JSP.

Comment: @bmargulies I don't know about you, but if I was doing something that has been considered a bad practice for years, I'd rather know about it, even if it wasn't an answer to my direct question. Sometimes I don't know enough to know what to ask, or if there's a better, more canonical way to do it.

Comment: @DaveNewton, glad to hear it. My preference is to put some thought into answers and not just try the first thing that works. At any rate, the FAQ for StackExchange says: 'What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.'

Comment: Revise: it's nice to *both* answer the factual question and offer an alternative.

Comment: I could however not agree more with bmargulies. Always **answer** the question, how bad it also is. Look at my answers for example, I often mention about the bad practices and other smells and holes in the posted code on an unrelated note. If you can't answer the question, just post a comment.

Comment: Sorry folks... I understand your position but do not agree. Nor does the FAQ. If the OP wants to come back and say, "hey, fine, but I can't use taglibs" then we'll proceed otherwise, but for now my answer is "don't do that" because scriptlets are such a poor practice that he really, really should be doing something else. Probably best to take this to meta if you are interested in discussing it further.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure all your quotes are straight quotes, not curvy ones.

Comment: Could be something to this. The first quote appears to be at column 17, but maybe the file has a strange encoding or something. It would be interesting to look at a hex dump of the file.

Comment: This is the correct answer for me! I am just doing a tutorial and the other answer makes no sense with so little knowledge. This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have copy pasted it from somewhere, make sure the double quotes are proper. I had the same issue when I copied it from a PDF, it was resolved once I corrected my double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSP works just fine with Tomcat 6. So, it's probably either some include-related issue or some previously compiled classes are not getting recompiled.

Try to clean up your Tomcat work directory and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Check " if you copied it from somewhere. I had the same error because of ".

<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@page isELIgnored=”false” %>

double quotes around the false are the wrong ones. Change it to " and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with Scott A's admonition to use JSTL instead of putting Java directly into the JSP the question deserves being explored a little further. I just encountered this myself for the first time and had to dig a bit ot answer it.

Technically the error means what it says. You're missing some quotes somewhere. The simplest would be something like in your h1 tag if it read:
<h1 align=center>
instead of what you have.
<h1 align="center">

Obviously there is nothing in the code snippet that you pasted which is missing quotes so I would explore a couple of things.

First, what does the output of your it.next() look like? Since you're pulling in a list called styles I wonder if something in there is making jasper think it's a style tag instead of text you are trying to render.

Second, I would explore Pradeep's answer and see what if there is some subtle issue pasting that was resolved when you pasted it here on stackoverflow. Specifically I would look for 'smart quotes' IE many text editors (including outlook and most of office) like to use different quotes on the front and back of quoted text.
IE

**'this is quoted text'**
becomes
**`this is quoted text'**

which can be difficult to notice.